# nginx: How to map a domain to another domain?

Tags: nginx, domain

I have a domain `example.com` and the server block looks something like this (it's a WordPress multisite):

```
server {
  server_name example.com www.example.com blog.example.com marketing.example.com;

  # other configurations
}
```

HTTPS is also set up with certbot (in case that matters).

Now I have another domain `example.net` and I want it to redirect to `example.com` (including all subdomains). For example, `blog.example.net` should redirect to `blog.example.com`. Is there a recommended way/pattern to achieve this in the nginx conf?

(Or, should be managed by the DNS in the VPS?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a dedicated `server` block with a regular expression `server_name` to capture the subdomain of `example.net` (if any) and use it in a `return` statement.

```
server {
    ...
    server_name "~^(?<name>.*\.)?example\.net$";
    return 301 $scheme://${name}example.com$request_uri;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) for more.